# SQL query that excludes fields that are null or empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects customers that don't have a barcode, like this:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  
       c.*, 
       ci.customer_street_address, 
       cty.city_name as customer_city 
FROM customer c 
left join customer_address ci using(customer_id)
left join customer_company cc using (customer_id)
left join city cty on cty.city_id = ci.city_id
left join `order` using (customer_id)  
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND (((customer_barcode IS NULL OR customer_barcode = '')))  
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

But it returns more results than expected. Customers barcode can be either null or empty space so I think the query is right, I tried inner join too instead of left join but I get too many results. For example, I select the number of customers that have a barcode and the number is 10 (which is correct) but the number of customers in my db without a barcode is 100 and I get 107.

Comment: Incorrect query: incomplete GROUP BY + obviously excess tables in FROM.

Comment: I would avoid the use of USING. It's not obvious to me if customer_id in this join left join customer_company cc using (customer_id) is comiing from customer_address or customer